# How might I write an operational definition for Vertical and/or Horizontal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, definition

I really don't want to have to rely on a forum website to tell me how I can solve my physics homework, but I honestly have no idea where to begin.  Can any of you guys explain how I might logically write an operational definition for Vertical without using anything that couldn't be understood by any other random person.  My teacher won't let us use gravity to explain it, and we can't use Horizontal unless we define that without using Vertical.   I honestly can't think of any possible definition for this, let alone an Operational Definition where we have to come up with a procedure to test if something is vertical.  Thanks a ton if you can help! This is from my kinematics unit, so that is why I tagged it that.

EDIT:  [here](https://www.bisd303.org/cms/lib/WA01001636/Centricity/Domain/627/Day%2016%20Phy%20F18.pdf) is the pdf containing the lesson and, on the last page, the question.

Comment: If your teacher gave you a written definition of the problem, include that here.  However he may be trying to get you to think about frames of reference, and that  without gravity or acceleration there is no way to tell one frame from another.  There are a lot of problems that become a lot easier if you use the right frame of reference.  So he may not be expecting a working answer.

Comment: I agree with @SherwoodBotsford. Please post the exact question.

Comment: @AaronStevens done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to do without knowing what tools you have, and what he considers 'use of gravity in an indirect way.

E.g.  "Vertical is the average  of the direction of the brightest 40% of locations of the surrounding sphere.  Because the sky is generally brighter than the ground, this would give you more or less straight up.

The counter argument is that the (more or less) round shape of a planet is due to gravity.  And that this definition is limited to a reasonably smooth part of a planet that has a thin enough atmosphere to have a bright sky.  A very small fraction of the cosmos.

You can be arbitrary.  Pick a direction, "That way is vertical."  Horizontal is a plane normal to that line.  This may be what he is looking for.

You could define it relative other forces than gravity.  E.g. Vertical is the direction that a magnetic north monopole test charge would move.  This is not a terribly useful definition for vertical, but it is a useful definition of 'south'.

Added after the link to the assignment.

The "all situations" clause is hard.

If you are on the surface of the earth or other body large enough to have a measurable gravitation field, then you can use a plumb bob.  Note that this doesn't work on a merry go round, or rather it will give you a constantly chanaging answer on a merry go round.  (Sometimes all you care about is the direction of local 'down'  You will need to constrain the problem, OR constrain the definition.

Note that  the earth is rotating.  Does this affect your answer?

If you are in orbit, the plumb bob won't work.  Or will it?  What would happen if you gently sent the plumb bob out on a 500 foot string?  Using rigid structures, you can make satellites keep a fixed orientation to their primary.

Suppose you are in orbit in a closed box.  No windows.  You can still determine a direction of down.  Two hints:  Tides.  Roche's limit.

Suppose you are in orbit around a body that is invisible.  (Shadow matter, dark matter)  That you are in orbit means that your velocity is changing. You can measure your velocity by doppler shifts from quasars.  Once you have a few measurements, (I think it takes 7 parameters to define an orbit, so 7 degrees of freedom 7 measurements?)  Once you have a defined orbit vertical is the direction to the focus  of the ellipse of your orbit.

For horizontal, the simplest empirical definition I can come up with a plane tangent to the surface of still liquid.  Again, constrained to the surface of a planet.